# Paypal - Magento redirects back to cart when more than one product is added upon checkout

Tags: checkout, cart, onepage-checkout, paypal, paypal-express

The issue I'm having appears to be related to Magento<->Paypal communication.

I have configured Paypal Website Standard payment method and can successfully "Check out with paypal" upon adding a single product to my cart, I'm quite sure this is the paypal-express method. If I add a second product to the cart and select "Check out with paypal" I'm redirected back to the cart.

If i select the Magento "Proceed to checkout" function, after selecting paypal as the payment method I am also redirected back to the cart.

I've turned logging on, however I'm not getting any additional entries in the exception.log after I corrected an intial IPN issue that I had.

Any thoughts or places I could start to look to resolve the issue?

Comment: Which version of Magento?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has since been resolved after moving Hosting providers, seems there was an issue at my webhost's end which caused this problem.